# creating popup dialog like facebook android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make popup dialog like in facebook app with pointing marker to the selection area.
here is an example how it should look like.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/9/facebookandroid.png/

please help if you know something about it.

Thanks in advance..

[image]

Comment: dinesh, i think you can create a QuickAction dialog for this.

Comment: see this [QuickAction Dialog in Android](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be your question would get solved from this

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple strategies that can solve this problem, but each solution has to deal with the placement of the triangle/pointer at the top of the dialog since it has to be positioned to indicate the user's selection.

I think the easiest way to solve this problem is:

1. Start an activity that has a transparent theme.  So, apply something like android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" to the Activity in the manifest.  If you want a Title Bar, do some searching for the right android-style.
2. Pass an extra to the activity that represents the navigation element chosen by the user.  this will be used by the activity to position the triangle pointer.
3. Handle this extra in the activity's onCreate() method by drawing the triangle/pointer in code.  This means you will want to call setContentView(...) in onCreate(), then get a reference to the ViewGroup (i.e. RelativeLayout, AbsoluteLayout, etc.).  Once you have that you can call ViewGroup#addView(View child, int index) to add the ImageView that represents the triangle.  You probably want to use index = 0.
4. Ensure that whatever View(s) you add programatically is/are not covered (i.e. hidden) by elements in the XML.
5. Adding the triangle is relatively easy, but positioning can get tricky.  First of all, the screenshot you posted assumes a fixed-width device, and that's just not true for an Android app in the market that needs to work on 1000s of screen sizes.  The Y-coordinate of the triangle/pointer is not a problem, since the height of the top-nav is probably hardcoded.  It's the X-coordinate that can get tricky.  What if the top-nav elements stretch?  Let's assume we have a robust/decent way to get the X-position where the center of the triangle/pointer should be.  Given that, I'd try using a vertical LinearLayout in my Activity and use an ImageView with a left-margin for the triangle/pointer.  That's just a guess and you'll probably have to tinker with this to get the right View elements and positioning strategy for your specific implementation.

Comment: One such robust/decent method might be to add a touch event handler on the top-nav and keep track of the x-coordinate of the touch/click.

Comment: Instead of creating activity i can also create dialog but i need it to be closed if the user touches on other then the popup area